# Google Charts hide only some series in legend

Tags: google-visualization, hide, legend, series

Is it possible to hide only some series in the legend.

I have a combo chart containing:

- amount of A
- amount of B
- amount of C

all displayed as one stacked column.

and also:

- amount/second of A
- amount/second of B
- amount/second of C

all displayed as separate lines within the same chart.

Now "amount of A" has the same color as "amount/second of A". This color should be displayed in the legend only once and labelled "A".

Is it possible to do that with Google Charts? If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove specific entries from the legend by setting the chart's `series.<series index>.visibleInLegend` options to `false` for the series you want to hide from the legend.  As an example, if the amount/second series are the 4th, 5th, and 6th data series in your data set, you could create a `series` option like this to hide them:

```
series: {
    3: {
        visibleInLegend: false
    },
    4: {
        visibleInLegend: false
    },
    5: {
        visibleInLegend: false
    }
}
```

The series index is counting data series only, not DataTable columns, so ignore your domain column and any special role columns you are using when determining the series index.